# how to change html view using binding in angular 6

Tags: binding, angular6, angular-components

I have an angular 6 project , I have a component for book like this

```
<div class="col-md-4 agileinfo_single_left">
    <img id="BigBookView" src="public/books/images/{{book.photo}}" alt=" " class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 agileinfo_single_right">
  <h1>{{book.name | uppercase}}</h1>
  <h2>Series: {{book.seriesName}}</h2>
  <h3>Author: {{book.author}}</h3>
  <h4></h4>
  <div class="w3agile_description">
    <h4>Summary : {{book.summary}}</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="snipcart-item block">
    <div class="snipcart-thumb agileinfo_single_right_snipcart">
       <h4 class="m-sing">Price: {{book.price}}$</h4>
       <h4 class="m-sing">Seller: {{book.seller}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="snipcart-details agileinfo_single_right_details">
      <form action="#" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

all of this is inside a modal and every time I choose a book and the modal is opened and suppose to show the book data in this html.
This is the component type script

```
export class BigBookViewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public book:Book = new Book();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public changeBook(newBook: Book) {
    console.log(this.book);
    this.book = newBook;
  }

}
```

using the function `changeBook` I send to this component a new book to show but the html and the UI don't chagne, even though I can see in the `console.log(this.book);` line that the book is indeed being sent.
How can I change the html to show a diffrent book?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the book on ngOnInit method. 
When assigning in the constructor the single instance of the component will keep the original book.

Comment: It doesn't work , the book is still undefined no matter what I change.
maybe it because I call this function from another component then 'this' is belong also to the other component

Comment: humm I would suspect the modal is messing somehow with the update event, try to change book to a BehaviorSubject<Book> and in the changeBook use this.book.emit(newBook)

Comment: can you build a stackblitz example on how you are loading this component in a modal?